# Website is slowed by Doctrine2

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I want to ask You, dear stackoverflow.com users, about Doctrine optimalization. I have one file with the following code:

```
define('PATH_LIB', '../framework/lib/');

$models = array('UserPermission.php');

require_once 'UserPermission.php';
require_once PATH_LIB."Doctrine/bootstrap.php";
$db = $entityManager;
$results = $db->find('UserPermission', 282);
```

and it's avaible by this hyperlink: http://test.gieromaniak.pl/doctrine.php

It concerns only one model (UserPermission.php):

```
<?php
/** @Entity @Table(name="users_permissions") */
class UserPermission {
    /** @Id @GeneratedValue @Column(type="integer") */
    protected $id;
}
```

The problem is, that this file is loading much slower with Doctrine. When the file is empty, download time is about 200ms. But when I have above content it's about 350ms.

How can I check, that the fault is on Doctrine's side? Is it Doctrine's fault at all? What could be slowing down this files execution if otherwise?

And for other examples:
http://test.gieromaniak.pl/dssdssdd
With Doctrine connection and one query to db download speed is about 500ms
With only Doctrine connection download speed is about 350ms
With none Doctrine connection download speed is about 200ms

Any suggestions?

Comment: It is probably a configuration bug. Doctrine likes to get ridiculously slow when configured badly. Do you have any caching turned on? At least ArrayCache

Comment: @ZolaKt Erm.... I don't know :D. Never used it, I think. What could be configured badly and how to turn on caching?

Comment: Look at the examples in the docs. You will see a cach object instanced depending on the server environment. http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/configuration.html

Answer (score 2):

Look into Redis (advanced key-value store) and this will solve the doctrine 2 error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted to profile the website yet? I would start there by running something like xdebug and using something like wincachegrind to parse the results. This will let you know which functions are slowing the website down and let you know where best to focus optimizations.

Comment: _Have you attempted to profile the website yet?_ <- what do You mean? I have never used xdebug before. For now, I managed to turn it on in my xampp server. It's working, because debugclient says so. How to take information about _which functions are slowing the website down_ from this client / xdebug?

Comment: What OS are you on? If windows just go download wincachegrind. It does pretty well. If not windows you can download webgrind or something similar. Just do a google search for xdebug parsing applications

Comment: I have downloaded _wincachegrind_... but how to parse informations from xdebug to this application?